# Commutator of spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator, lie-algebra

Suppose we are given $\left[S_X, S_Y\right]$, $\left[S_Y, S_Z\right]$ and $\left[S_Z, S_X\right]$, that is the spin operator commutation relations, can we then determine the matrix representation of these operators?
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_{X}S_{Y} - S_{Y}S_{X} &= iS_Z\\
S_{Y}S_{Z} - S_{Z}S_{Y} &= iS_X\\
S_{Z}S_{X} - S_{X}S_{Z} &= iS_Z\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Is there a way to solve this system of equations? And can we do it in any dimension?

Comment: It is the algebra for the SU(2) Lie group. Some knowledge of Lie groups and Lie algebras would help and provide the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @flippiefanus I have not yet taken any course that has Lie Algebra. Can you please suggest me some sources or other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: As @flippiefanus said, this is the Lie algebra for the Lie group $SO(3)\equiv SU(2)$. There should be many resources (lecture notes and texts) online to learn about Lie Groups. I would recommend a simple and quick explanation in Chapter 4 of Gauge Theory of Elementary Particle Physics, by Ta-Pei Cheng and Ling-Fong Li